# Decoding jquery.rd-mailform.min.c.js plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know how to decode this file:

`jquery.rd-mailform.min.c.js`

It seems to be either encoded, or, rather, obfuscated, starting with

```
var _0xe86e = ["\x6A\x51\x75\x65\x72\x79",....
(function (_0x625ex1,....
```

`Hex decoders` are not much of a help with this file, that is why I am thinking that it is obfuscated code.

It is a `jquery plugin` which converts `select` into `ul dropdown`, fails without throwing any error on `IE11` but works OK on `Firefox` and `Chrome`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just run into this problem because I needed to localize the error texts that the plugin shows, I found this page: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/ which converts from hexadecimal to text and viceversa so I could replace the texts in the plugin. So, in resume, I beautified the plugin (in http://jsbeautifier.org/), then looked for the strings and manually replaced them for the localized strings in hexadecimal. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i used https://encoder.internetwache.org/ and was useful to decode validation error texts

i could re encode my customized errors text using HEX(JS) option from left menu

Even you can decode all code from jquery.rd-mailform.min.c.js file and find functions